# ExcelDna CustomTaskPane Example Exception

Tags: excel, excel-dna, customtaskpane

I tried to use CustomTaksPane example from ExcelDNA package and got the following error:

**"An exception occurred while calling function "OnShowTCP". The exception message is 
Exception has been thrown by the target of invocation"**

I use Excel 2010 under Windows 7.

Any ideas?

Comment: I made test at another mashine. it looks like it works with 32bit version of Windows7/Excel 2010...

Answer (score 1):

A common issue with showing the CTP is when running Excel either:

1. "As Administrator" under a UAC-restricted user account - this has been fixed in the beta version of Excel-DNA v 0.30, which you can download here: http://exceldna.codeplex.com/releases/view/95861.
2. Under an account which does not have permissions to write to HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes. I hope to handle this unusual setting with a better message in future.

Comment: Looks like this is not an issue. I have administrative privilege, as I could edit this key with regedit32, I have downloaded version 3.0, unfortunately the same error...

Comment: Yes. Ribbon is appear. Button is in place, the only problem takspane. I made a check on 32 bit version of excel/Windows7 looks like it work.

Comment: Check for Disabled Items...? It would be better to follow up on the Excel-DNA Google group (http://groups.google.com/group/exceldna).

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like it is similar to the problem reported here: https://exceldna.codeplex.com/workitem/9366

Are you trust center settings set to 'Require Application Add-ins to be signed by Trusted Publisher'? If so and the addin is signed by a trusted publisher, the addin will load correctly as will the COM server for the Ribbon but for some reason the COM server dynamically registered for the CTP does not load. If one drops the Trust Center settings then the addin works fine as is.

Comment: The problem with CTPs and high Trust Center settings went away with recent (April 2015) revisions from github. See recent updated to https://exceldna.codeplex.com/workitem/9366 for more details.